# SQL JDBC template drop table issue: drop table with FK and Unique index (JDBC template)

Tags: sql, spring-mvc, spring-security, hsqldb

I am using JDBC template for my web+MVC+Security (using Spring 2.5, Spring security 2.0.4) for the user authentication with roles in it. When I am trying to execute it, its giving me the following error:

```
Mar 06, 2012 10:10:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 06, 2012 10:11:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 06, 2012 10:11:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourcePopulator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataAccessContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE TABLE USERS(USERNAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,PASSWORD VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,ENABLED BOOLEAN NOT NULL);]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Table already exists: USERS in statement [CREATE TABLE USERS]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE TABLE USERS(USERNAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,PASSWORD VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,ENABLED BOOLEAN NOT NULL);]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Table already exists: USERS in statement [CREATE TABLE USERS]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:429)
    at springapp1.service.HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator.afterPropertiesSet(HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator.java:23)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table already exists: USERS in statement [CREATE TABLE USERS]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:422)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
    ... 35 more
```

HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator.java (JDBC template)

```
public class HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator implements InitializingBean {

    private JdbcTemplate template;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(template, "dataSource required");

        // add tables to represent admin core-domain instances.
        template
                .execute("CREATE TABLE USERS(USERNAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                        + "PASSWORD VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,"
                        + "ENABLED BOOLEAN NOT NULL);");
        template
                .execute("CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES(USERNAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,AUTHORITY VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS FOREIGN KEY(USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS(USERNAME));");
        template
                .execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_AUTH_USERNAME ON AUTHORITIES(USERNAME,AUTHORITY);");

        // add tables to represent bug tracking domain instances.
        template
                .execute("CREATE TABLE PROJECTS(ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(200) NOT NULL);");
        // insert data here
        template
                .execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('disabled','disabled',FALSE);");
        template.execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('admin','admin',TRUE);");

        template
                .execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('username','password',TRUE);");
        template.execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('user','pass',TRUE);");

    //ADMIN-ROLES

        template
                .execute("INSERT INTO AUTHORITIES VALUES('admin','ROLE_USER');");

        template
                .execute("INSERT INTO AUTHORITIES VALUES('admin','ROLE_ADMIN');");
    //USER-ROLES
        template
                .execute("INSERT INTO AUTHORITIES VALUES('username','ROLE_USER');");
 }

    public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

So, I add the following code to the HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator class:

```
//Delete tables if exist
    template
    .execute("ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS;");
    template
    .execute("ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP INDEX IX_AUTH_USERNAME;");
    template
    .execute("DROP TABLE PROJECTS IF EXISTS;");
    template
    .execute("DROP TABLE USERS IF EXISTS;");
    template
    .execute("DROP TABLE USERS IF AUTHORITIES;");
```

Now it gives me the following error:

```
Mar 06, 2012 10:11:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 06, 2012 10:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 06, 2012 10:16:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourcePopulator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataAccessContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS;]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Constraint not found FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS in table: AUTHORITIES in statement [ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS;]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Constraint not found FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS in table: AUTHORITIES in statement [ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:429)
    at springapp1.service.HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator.afterPropertiesSet(HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator.java:23)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Constraint not found FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS in table: AUTHORITIES in statement [ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:422)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
    ... 35 more
```

And this is my dataAccessContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- business stuff below -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourcePopulator" class="springapp1.service.HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I think I am doing something wrong with the SQL statements, but not exactly sure what it is? Can someone help me with this one? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HSQLDB (especially version 2.2.x) you don't have to drop constraints and indexes on a table before you drop the table.

`DROP TABLE x IF EXISTS` will drop the table, including any FK or index on the table
`DROP TABLE y IF EXISTS CASCADE` will drop the table as above, as well as any FK defined on other tables that reference table y

Therefore you should be able to avoid the SQLException when some table or constraint has not been defined.